# Are Unix/Linux systems vulnerable to leaking global kernel objects?

Tags: windows, linux, unix, resources, operating-system

In Windows there're objects maintained by the system - events, file access handles, windows, timers, etc, that are not unlimited so that all programs in the system can create something like no more than 50k objects (I'm not sure of the exact figure, but it's not very critical for this question).

So if some program runs for a very long time and creates lots of objects and doesn't release them (exactly like a memory leak, but here system objects are leaked) the system finally runs out of objects and other programs that try to do something that requires creating any new system objects start getting error indications from system functions. Like for example, program A runs and leaks all objects available to the system and then program B tries to open a file and fails just because the system has no resources to service that request. The only solution at that point is to restart program A so that leaked resources are reclaimed by the system.

Does the same problem exist on Unix/Linux systems or are they somehow protected against that?

Comment: I'm not sure 'leaking' is the correct term.  Maybe 'exhaustion' would be more accurate.  The kernel does its utmost to ensure that there are no resource leaks - as in completely lost resources.  It cannot do much about ill-behaved programs that consume lots of resources - except ensure that the mess is cleaned up when the programs terminate.  And, on Linux, in the case of memory abuse, it launches the OOM Killer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They're subject to the same problems, but can to some degree be hardened/limited. Often by default, there's limits per process that's *way* below anything that would cause systemwide problems. All you have to do is start a lot of processes though. Some of these limits can be viewed by the `ulimit` command. Some *nixes have the possibility to set limits on a per user basis (see /etc/security/limits.conf on some linux systems)

But in cases where you remove the limit, or have a whole lot of processes doing bad stuff, the system wide total limit is usually bound by available resources(memory)

if you want a demonstration of resource limitation, run [this command](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_bomb) in a bash shell and see if your system is still usable:

```
:(){ :|:& };:
```

Comment: Warning: on some unix systems, the fork bomb makes the OS completely unresponsive (requiring a hard reboot). Don't try this at home (much less at work)!

Comment: I didn't know emoticons could kill!

Answer (score 2):

Two of the error numbers in Unix/Linux are:

- ENFILE (23): Too many open files in system
- EMFILE (24): Too many open files

The first is a system-wide limit, the second a per-process limit.  The system-wide limit is usually sufficiently large that most systems do not run into it these days, but in the days of PDP-11 computers, it (ENFILE) was a real problem.